# SQL + PHP Search In Hierarchy

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with all of our users (nearly 2000 users):

```
 username         manager         isvip
 bob              alice           false
 alice            henry           false
 bart             henry           true
 henry                            true
```

For Bob, I have to find Henry (because bob < alice < henry = vip).

I tried to do some loops to find the manager until the manager is a vip, but it is not optimized at all, and it is very long for 2000 users.

Can I find in an easy way in SQL + PHP the vip for a user?

Comment: Welcome, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide some code you wrote.

Comment: show your code which you tried

Comment: Show what you tried and show tables structures with some example data and the desired output